# setting get_absolute_url when using a router

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Comment app and I would like my Commentserializer to display the exact URL of each instance of Comment. I know that I have to use the get_absolute_url of the Comment model. But i cannot connect my viewnames from my router to the get_absolute_url.

Here is my Model :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
content = models.TextField(max_length=150)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete = models.CASCADE
)
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
parent = models.ForeignKey(
    "self",
    on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    blank=True,
    null=True
)
datestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
objects = CommentManager()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.content[:30])

def save(self):
    self.object_id = self.parent.id
    super(Comment, self).save()

def children(self):
    return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("comments-details", args=[str(self.id)])

@property
def is_parent(self):
    if self.parent is None:
        return False
    return True
```

and here is my router :

```
router = router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('api/comments', CommentViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use "comment-details" as a viewname. 
The end Goal is to display a JSON like that :

```
{ url : 'blabla/comments/{pk}/details }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay It was easy to fix. Just use a HyperlinkedModelSerializer and add 'url' to your fields like so :

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = [
        "url",
        "datestamp",
        "content",
        "is_parent",
        "object_id",
        "children"
    ]
```